# Copy all the files from a specific date and above from one directory to another in UNIX. File contains date in the file name

Tags: linux, unix-timestamp

I need to copy all the files from a specific date and above from one directory to another in UNIX. File name contains date & Timestamp as shown below. I just numbered them to better view.

**Example:**

1. HUX_CRUX_ING_2022110301311069822123
2. HUX_CRUX_ING_2022110208311078822626
3. HUX_CRUX_ING_2022110105311073822123
4. HUX_CRUX_ING_2022103102319072262122 -- Need to copy this file and
   all    the above files to another folder
5. HUX_CRUX_ING_2022103002314076212423
6. HUX_CRUX_ING_2022102909318077242825
7. HUX_CRUX_ING_2022102806314078222123

I'm working as an ETL Developer and new to Unix.

Comment: I'd strongly consider using "find -mtime -exec" (or equivalent).  Look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118521/copy-files-modified-after-specific-date-using-cp-switches) or [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118521/copy-files-modified-after-specific-date-using-cp-switches) for a few examples.

Comment: `mtime` is based on file modificaiton, which may or may not be an accurate reflection of the times in the file names.  If they all have the same prefix before the date, you can sort them lexicographically.  That's the glorious benefit of using the YYYY-MM-DD order for dates!